# Underscore template can't access data model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am having difficulty accessing model data with underscore, nothing is appearing on screen and I'm not getting any errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my templating area

```
<script type='text/template' id='ListContainerView'>
 <p> <%= ListItemModel.id %> </p>
 <p> <%= ListItemModel.network %> </p>
 <p> <%= ListItemModel.created_by_id %> </p>
</script>
```

Collection

```
var ListItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
baseUrl: '/api/get_accounts',
url: '/api/get_accounts',
model: ListItemModel,
total: 0,
// Sample data
TESTDATA: {"status":"ok","posts":[{"id":"1","schedule":"2020-0417 17:00:00","utc_offset":"420","project_id":"1","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 1 (just text, approved)","data":[],"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:41:03","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"2","schedule":"2020-0419 19:00:00","project_id":"1","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 2 (text with image, approved)  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.","data":{"pictures":["https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9T6n0UUwAAOBaU.jpg"],"image_added":"true","picture":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9T6n0UUwAAOBaU.jpg","type":"photo"},"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","rejection_message_manager":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:42:34","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"3","schedule":"2020-0421 22:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 3 (link, approved) http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/","data":{"image_added":"true","pictures":["http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/img/2015/07/17/Rick%26MortyS02_fbsearchTn.jpg"],"picture":"http://i.cdn.turner.com/adultswim/big/img/2015/07/17/Rick%26MortyS02_fbsearchTn.jpg","link":"http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/","name":"Watch Rick and Morty on Adult Swim","caption":"www.adultswim.com","description":"Every episode of Rick and Morty is now on AdultSwim.com for free. Rick is a mad scientist who drags his grandson, Morty, on crazy sci-fi adventures. Their escapades often have potentially harmful consequences for their family and the rest of the world. Join Rick and Morty on AdultSwim.com as they trek through alternate dimensions, explore alien planets, and terrorize Jerry, Beth, and Summer.","domain":"www.adultswim.com","type":"link"},"customer_approved":"1","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:43:29","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"4","schedule":"2020-0424 17:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 4 (text, pending)","data":[],"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:43:48","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"5","schedule":"2020-0426 19:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 5 (picture, pending)","data":[],"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:44:03","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"},{"id":"6","schedule":"2020-0428 21:00:00","network":"facebook","network_name":"TestFacebookPage","network_thumb":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17634406_1854330461448271_6787736791983791423_n.jpg?oh=e4c3a3573c0fc59359422cfd66a3865a&oe=598721E7","message":"Test Post 6 (link, pending) https://www.reddit.com/","data":{"image_added":"true","pictures":["https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/2Hwaff37fC4f37j-3orrbjVAOVBChqbdm_dXeIhjlNw.jpg"],"picture":"https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/2Hwaff37fC4f37j-3orrbjVAOVBChqbdm_dXeIhjlNw.jpg","link":"https://www.reddit.com/","name":"reddit: the front page of the internet","caption":"www.reddit.com","description":"reddit: the front page of the internet","domain":"www.reddit.com","type":"link"},"customer_approved":"0","manager_approved":"1","rejection_message":"","created_at":"2020-0413 17:44:19","created_by":"admin","created_by_id":"1","created_by_name":"John Admin"}],"total":"6"},

initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.total = this.TESTDATA.total;
    this.reset(this.TESTDATA.posts);
}

})
```

Views...

```
var ListContainerView = SOCIView.extend({
template: _.template($('#ListContainerView').text()),
className: 'ListContainerView'
})

var SOCIView = Backbone.View.extend({
render: function() {
    if (typeof this.beforeRender === 'function') {
        this.beforeRender();
    }

    var modelData = { };
    if (this.model && this.model instanceof Backbone.Model) {
        modelData = this.model.toJSON();
    }

    if (typeof this.template === 'function') {
        this.$el.html(this.template(modelData));
    }

    if (typeof this.afterRender === 'function') {
        this.afterRender();
    }
    return this;
  }
})
```

and script inside HTML...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // Instantiate and render Backbone view
      $('.home_body').append( new ListContainerView({
          collection: new ListItemCollection(),
      }).render().el)
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toJSON` method on a Backbone model gives you a simple copy of the model attributes. In your case, this:

```
modelData = this.model.toJSON();
```

should give you an object that looks like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  schedule: "2020-0417 17:00:00",
  utc_offset: "420",
  ...
}
```

Notice that there is no `ListItemModel` anywhere in that object. That object would be suitable for a template that looks like this:

```
<p> <%= id %> </p>
<p> <%= network %> </p>
<p> <%= created_by_id %> </p>
```

If you really wanted the `ListItemModel` prefixes in the template then you'd want to say:

```
this.template({ ListItemModel: modelData })
```

when calling the template function.

Alternatively you could compile the template using the `{variable: 'ListItemModel'}` option to [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) and leave the template and `this.template` call alone. So your view would have:

```
template: _.template($('#ListContainerView').html(), { variable: 'ListItemModel'),
```

and the rest wouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Where you define your template for the `ListContainerView`, I think using `.text()` (instead of `.html()`) might be causing your problem. Instead try

```
template: _.template($('#ListContainerView').html())
```

and see if it works.

Jquery's `.text()` ignores html markup like `<span>` or `<strong>` tags (etc), so it may be removing your templating tags `<% ... %>` as well, giving you just a few spaces.

Comment: Great suggestion, unfortunately nothing changed. I feel I'm most likely accessing the data incorrectly with ListItemModel.id.. I can't put my finger on it...

Comment: Sorry I saw the one bug, but I should have looked closer... a couple of things I can see: your `ListContainerView` has a template, but no render method, so when you call render in your script, it wouldn't do anything. In the render you should give the model data from the collection to the template to render somehow.

Comment: The way you are set up, giving the `ListContainerView` a `render` method that appends the template (with each model from the collection fed in) to it's `el` might work.

Comment: When your template is in a `<script>` container with an appropriate `content-type` attribute, `.html` is what you want. The `<script type='text/template'>` container is used specifically to avoid problems with "text the looks sort of like HTML" in your templates.